# Как ускорить загрузку фонового видео на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Фоновое видео грузится долго. PageSpeed Insights показывает скорость 10 из 100. Использую jquery-плагин YTPlayer. Как как можно опитимизировать данный момент?

https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/deeKWK

```
$(".js-video-poster").mb_YTPlayer();
```

Comment: А зачем вам плагин ? Чем функционал тега video не устраивает ?

Comment: @Hikikomori, вроде, если включить iframe в тег video, ничего не появится. Или вы чисто про iframe? А в таком случае можно будет наложить на видео контент, например, заголовок, как сейчас? Как убирать тогда контролы?

Comment: Какой iframe ? Зачем ? Скачиваете ваше видео с youtube, подключаете его в video, делаете его абсолютом и задаете z-index: -1;  Про контролы и прочие атрибуты здесь - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: А с ютуба без лагов сделать не получится?

Comment: Технически можете попробовать подключить в video прямую ссылку на видео с youtube. Как её получить, найдете наверное.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Hikikomori/pen/eKaYNo

Comment: @Hikikomori, а откуда сгенерирована такая ссылка? У меня не проигрывается видео почему-то..

Comment: При помощи одного из сервисов-загрузчиков. Я использовал savefromnet. Насчет воспроизведения, я так полагаю у вас хром. Это он такой заботливый и не воспроизводит по умолчанию видео со звуком (есть он или нет). Добавление атрибута muted решило проблему

Comment: Не забудьте добавить атрибут loop, если нужен повтор

Comment: @Hikikomori, спасибо большое, ещё б ссылка была в стиле moC98CP-NRA, а то хз, как клиент должен вставлять такую ссылку :)